# Handling identifiers that begin with a reserved word

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter, lexical-analysis

I am presently writing my own lexer and am wondering how to correctly handle the situation where an identifier begins with a reserved word. Presently the the lexer matches the whole first part as a reserved word and then the rest separately because the reserved word is the longest match ('self' vs 's' in the example below).

For example with the rules:

```
RESERVED_WORD := self
IDENTIFIER_CHAR := [A-Z]|[a-z]
```

Applied to:

```
selfIdentifier
```

'self' is matched as `RESERVED_WORD` and 'I' and onwards is matched as `IDENTIFIER_CHAR` when the whole string should be matched as `IDENTIFIER_CHAR`s

Comment: If that lexer is regexp-based, then wouldn't an assertion such as `(?!self)[a-z]+` do?

Comment: How can `Identifier` match IDENTIFIER? IDENTIFIER only matches one character. If it matched multiple characters it should be the longest match.

Comment: @rici:  I don't think his lexer actually uses regexes; these examples probably represent what he thinks he has.     And, he made a mistake in writing them down.  I'm sure he meant ([A-Z]|[a-z])+

Comment: @irabaxter: maybe but it might be helpful for OP to field the question. In the post, there is awareness of the longest match rule, but the matches compared are `self` and `s`. As written, that is correct but it leaves open the question of how Identifier matches IDENTIFIER.

Comment: @rici You are right, that was a mistake in my question. I've edited it now.

Comment: @Joshua:  er,  "the whole string should be matched as IDENTIFIER_CHARs"??  Yes, it arguably *could* be matched that way.  Arguably the match to reservied word then IDENTIFIER_CHARs is perfectly valid, too.  Either you have to accept the ambiguity (you'll find out about these in grammars soon enough) or you have to make a rule about which match wins when there are multiple matches.   You can decide either way, and force that choice.   You seem to be complaining that you have a choice, you don't like one of them, and you aren't forcing it the way you want.  OK, force it the other way.

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer in most lexer generators is that the regex that matches the longest sequence wins.   To break a tie between two regexes that match the exact same amount, is to prefer the first regex in the order in which they appear in your definitions file.

You can simulate this effect in your lexer.  Then "selfIdentifier" would be treated as an identifier.

If you are writing a efficient lexer, you'll have a single finite state machine that branches from one state to another based on the current character class.  In this case, you'll have several states that can be terminal states, and *are* terminal states if the FSA cannot shift to another state.  You can assign a token type to each such terminal state; the token type will be unique.

Comment: How would this work when `RESERVED_WORD` matches 4 characters but `IDENTIFIER_CHAR` matches just one?

Comment: If the FSA can transit to another state, it does.   As it goes through a terminal state, it records that state.  If it arrives at an end state which is NOT a terminal state, it generates the token for the last terminal state it went through, and backs up the input stream accordingly.